# Умножение матриц в LinkedList

Tags: java, матрицы, linked-list, умножение

Надо умножить матрицы, коэффициенты которых находятся в `LinkedList`.

Смог сделать такое:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> matrix1 = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> matrix2 = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    LinkedList<Integer> temporaryM1 = matrix1.get(i);
    LinkedList<Integer> subList = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            LinkedList<Integer> temporaryM2 = matrix2.get(k);
            res += temporaryM1.get(k) * temporaryM2.get(j);
        }
        subList.add(res);
    }
    multiplied.add(subList);
}
```

Но я не знаю, как выполнять умножения, когда матрица представляется одним списком, т.е. не

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> matrix1 = new LinkedList<>();
```

а

```
LinkedList<Integer> matrix1 = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так смог разобраться
должно быть так

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                int res = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                    res += m1.get(i * n + k) * m2.get(k * n + j);
                }
                result.add(res);
            }
        }
```